# UK Standard visitor visa type for Tourism or Family?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to travel with my wife from India to meet her sister in the UK. Her sister is a British citizen and lives in Scotland. We are planning to visit London for few days and then visit the sister's home in Scotland. We are Indian citizens and we will be doing some tourism as well.

After selecting standard visa, I have to choose the reason for the visit, e.g., Tourism, Family etc. Which should I select, since we will do both?

As far as I understand, based on the selection, the application type will be different and I dont want to make a mistake.

Comment: Visit Family since you are saying it's your primary purpose. You can tour around on that premise as well. You don't have to stay at her home all the time

Comment: I have added few edits as well Hanky. Can you kindly see them and let me know if it is still the same comment you have. Apologies for the rapid edit.

Comment: With such a great answer below any further comments from Me are redundant :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see the problem here.  You are seeing a form with purple branding and some drop down lists (see the question's edit history) that looks something like this...

[image]

---

But for the situation you have described, you want a Standard Visitor Visa, and the correct form looks like this...

---

[image]

---

So the bottom line is that you are filling out the wrong form.

The Gateway for the Standard Visitor Visa is at [Apply for a UK Visa](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa), and the welcome page looks like this...

[image]

---

Once you begin filling out the form, you will see that the branding is different and the questions prefer radio buttons as opposed to drop-down lists.  They changed the forms earlier this year and the migration process continues.

---

Why are there two different forms? The old form had problems, perhaps the largest problem is that it did not acknowledge the existence of the Standard Visitor Visa.  It also asked questions that **should not be asked of visitors** like "*Do you know anyone in the UK?*".  So they made a separate form. They did this in conjunction with external members of the public to assure that they wouldn't have *a flood of complaints* and that all the various requirements were adequately represented. The similar questions exist on the old form because...  well because UKVI takes a long time to rationalise their various forms.

---

Once you begin filling out the form, you'll see that it's much more straight-forward and amenable to those seeking a Standard Visitor Visa.

To repeat, the correct form is at [Apply for a UK Visa](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa).